# Saber se um processo é crítico

Tags: c#, .net

Se meu programa fechar um processo crítico, haverá uma tela-azul. Então, como eu posso saber se um processo é crítico? Se este processo for crítico, então meu programa não o fechará.

[image]

Comment: E você consegue matar um processo crítico numa boa?

Comment: @LINQ sim, porque meu app é executado como admininstrador